# TextInput Alignment Not Centered iOS React-Native

Tags: react-native

Why does iOS not center the text input control?
I am including the render and stylesheet
code:

[left android, right ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0t62.png)

```
render() {
  return (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
           style={styles.input}
           onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
           underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
           value={this.state.text}
           placeholder= 'username'
           />
  </View>
)
}


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#13493A'
}

 input: {
   height: 40,
   width: 250,
   borderRadius: 5,
   backgroundColor: '#598176',
   color: 'white',
   marginTop: 30,
   textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance,
Anthonie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on the issue tracker, this appears to be a bug in React Native on iOS: [#11892](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11892) So your code should work but doesn't. There is a listed workaround which is to add `alignSelf: 'center'` to the TextInput's styles ([see example](https://snack.expo.io/HyBStJ76e)).